# Library for subsequences of elements from the input iterable

Tags: java

I have been searching for a while but I haven't found an equivalent library in java that does what [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) does. I refuse to believe that such a library doesn't exist.

Could someone point me to a java library that returns subsequences of elements ( combinations or permutations ) given an iterator over a container.

Answer (score -1):

check google's guava http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/.
http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/index.html

Comment: i have, but i didn't find it. could you point me to the class/function itself

Comment: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#partition(java.util.Iterator, int)

Comment: Um, I don't think that's what the OP's looking for, but [this](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release12/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#permutations(java.util.Collection)) might be.

Comment: yup, that gives me permutations. is there something similar for combinations with/without replacement ?